# The Application Split Challenge - fast+easy RPC technology?

Tags: windows, architecture, real-time, distributed, rpc

the following tries to get an idea of which technologies would be suitable for a specific (as outlined) distributed/RPC problem. If something is not clear, am am very happy to add more details, but please request these in a *comment* and not in an "answer". Thanks.

First I will describe the current situation, and then follows what we want to achieve and the actual question. Despite this being a rather long post to get some context, the question itself is rather short (see at the end).

## The Application Split challenge

### Application description:

The app allows the user to configure a number of hardware devices(*)
 and then communicate with these to control and collect measurement 
channels of a physical experiment.

(*) Hardware devices include temperature sensors, pressure sensors, 
motors, ... Communication ranges from serial port communication, 
TCP/UDP communication to interfacing with the drivers of 3rd party 
plugin cards.

Control involves sending commands to the various hardware devices 
to configure them according to the protocols they support. 
Measuring involves getting the data from (some of) these devices.

We are hard pressed to keep the whole thing running as customers 
demand more and more channels at higher sample rates and we have to 
keep up with writing the data+timestamps we get from all devices to 
disk, display a subset of the data and still keep the system 
responding properly.

### Current situation:

```
[ DisplayAndControl.exe      ]

  ||                    /\
  || DLL Interface      ||
  ||                    || Window Messages (SendMessage, PostMessage)
  ||                    ||
  \/                    ||

[ ChannelManager.dll         ]
```

- ChannelManager.dll (Native C++ DLL on Windows)

  - Manages n data channels (physical measurement variables)
  - Each channel holds a shifting arbitrary number of samples with
    high-precision timestamps
  - Allows to group channels and write their ongoing updates or 
    historical values ("measurement") to disk
  - Calculations with channels (arithmetic, integration, mean 
    values, etc.)
  - Interfaces with (realtime) hardware devices to get the timestamps
    and values of channels
  - Get value+timestamp from hardware and save in internal
    ring buffer for channel
- DisplayAndControl.exe (Native C++ MFC App on Windows)

  - Control the functions of ChannelManager.dll (configure channels
    and HW devices)
  - Live display current values/timestamps/changes of all channels
  - Graph values of (groups of) channels in diagrams
  - print diagrams and tables of channel values

**Summary of current situation:**

The application as it is at the moment is already somewhat modular 
in that the (main) executable does the display+interaction and the 
(one of several) DLL does the data management (saving of live data 
to disk, communication with devices, etc.)

From a performance POV, communication btw. the display module and 
the data management module is optimally performant at the moment.

### New situation:

```
[ DisplayAndControl.exe      ]

  ||                     /\
  || ? RPC/Messaging     ||
  ||                     || ? RPC/Messaging
  ||                     ||
  \/                     ||

[ ChannelManager.exe (same PC or another)  ]
```

**Summary of the envisioned new situation:**

For usability, performance and safety reasons, we wish to split up 
this Windows app into two separate applications, so that the 
performance (and safety) sensitive ChannelManager module can run as 
a separate process possibly on a separate Windows PC.

*Additionally*, since we're already going to split this, we will 
allow for multiple DisplayAndControl.exe apps connected to one 
single ChannelManager.exe.

One QUESTION now is what technology we should use to facilitate the 
communication btw. the now two (or, rather, `1 : small_n`) applications.

Performance is important, because a lot of data travels btw. the 
two applications and latency should be kept to a minimum. It "only" 
needs to work on Windows, but it should be usable from native C++ 
only which makes all purely .NET based technologies unattractive. 
(Note: Porting parts of DisplayAndControl.exe to .NET/WPF is 
planned, but ChannelManager.exe should stay pure native, as we 
don't want any .NET stuff running inside this process.)

*Regarding latency*: It is important that we achieve some level of
soft-realtime in the sense that small latency is acceptable, but 
large and especially varying latency is not acceptable for usability 
and safety reasons. Therefore any protocol that would help in 
getting some sort of (soft) realtime behavior would be preferred.

RPC technologies we've looked at:

- WCF (or .NET remoting) - Is dotnet only, therefore not 
  attractive. Performance figures are also not very good.
- (D)COM - COM is great for Windows RPC communication, but it 
  breaks down once you have to have inter-PC comm because it is 
  horrible to get the security settings working in a corporate IT 
  network.
- CORBA - We have had good experience with CORBA communications in 
  the past. The communication is easy to get working; there's not 
  much infrastructure overhead; it works well from C++; writing 
  a .NET wrapper is pretty trivial. The problem with CORBA is that
  it's somewhat complicated to use correctly in C++ (people will use
  a lot of time on chasing memory leaks, esp. inexperienced C++ 
  devs). It also will be a learning curve for every developer and
  every new developer, as no one expects people to "know" CORBA 
  nowadays. Also, it might not perform as well as we'd like it to and
  as far as I know there's no readily available realtime support.
- Thrift - still looks half-baked to use in our scenario.
- ICE (from ZeroC) - I would prefer ICE over CORBA anytime, after all
  it promises to be a "better CORBA" and I think it does deliver on
  that. However, their licensing policy is very suboptimal as they do not sell development licenses but only license per 
  installation. (Well that's what they told us last time we asked end of 2009.) Their licensing policy also suggests that any 3rd party possibly interested in interfacing with our modules would first have to negotiate a license contract with ZeroC too.
- Open MPI - Message Passing interface seems to be targeted at 
  scenarios with lots of clients "heavily" distributed. Doesn't seem
  to fit our problem.
- Writing our own communication layer using TCP/UDP - Oh my. I'd 
  rather not :-)
- Google Protocol Buffers - Is *not* an RPC technology.
- Distributed Shared Memory - Well. This got thrown in by a few 
  devs and *I* for one am neither sure if there's a working 
  implementation nor if it fit's our problem.

So again the QUESTION - **what "RPC"-like technology would you prefer 
in this situation and why?**

Comment: Do all the datapoints need to be taken as a consistent whole? Or should they instead be a stream of updates? Can SNMP provide the simple datapoints to your clients, and handle commands through another channel?

Comment: @sarnold: Data transfer and control-comm doesn't necessarily have to be on the same channel. I'm not sure that SNMP would be a good choice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can elaborate on Johnny's answer. CORBA provides a robust infrastructure with services that go far beyond simple RPC. As your distributed application grows, you can use CORBA features to manage the mapping between interface and implementation, to provide secure connections, etc. As an RPC, CORBA provides the means for easy synchronous or asynchronous invocations.

The learning curve isn't that steep either. While some of the terms are a little arcane, the concepts such as managed (counted) references should be familiar to today's C++ programmers. And when the C++0x mapping is available, it will be even easier. Training is available to help make this transition even easier.

You mentioned not knowing about realtime support. In fact, CORBA for C++ has rich RT support. There is a RT CORBA specification and several C++ ORBs that implement it. TAO, which is open source and commercially supported, has extensive RT support, including the RT_ORB, RT_POA, an TAO-Specific RT Event service. With these tools you are able to designate priority levels for threads in the ORB, and have separate communication channels for different priority levels.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a look at Thrift. While it looks half-baked, I believe it's only the documentation that's lacking - the implementation is quite solid.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe we should check again.

Answer (score 0):

CORBA should perform well and there are people with experience. We realize that the IDL to C++ mapping is hard to use, there is a RFP from the OMG asking for a new IDL to C++0x mapping, that should make it much easier to use

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you could elaborate some why you think CORBA would be a good (better) solution for this problem.